# How to Create a new Enterprise Application with SAML SSO in Azure AD using Graph API or Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to automate the creation of new Apps in Azure AD with support for SSO with SAML. Using the regular New-AzureADApplication or New-AzureADServicePrincipal commands from Powershell does not offer any option to register a application with that support. The closest thing I was able to get is to use the following tags when creating the service principal.

"8adf8e6e-67b2-4cf2-a259-e3dc5476c621",
"WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryCustomSingleSignOnApplication",
"WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryGalleryApplicationNonPrimaryV1",
"WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"

This makes the Sign On option appear under the Enterprise Application, but it breaks the rest as the SAML settings were not setup, and there is not support for doing that in the powershell commands or Graph API.

Is this scenario supported at all ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want full custom SAML SSO support (i.e. what you get from Enterprise apps > New application > Non-gallery application), what you're trying to do is not yet supported.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if there is any plan to support that? We are managing around 200 apps in my company right now and we need a way to automate that.

Comment: Yes, this will be supported eventually.

Answer (score 1):

the guid is probably an unnecessary tag.  looks like as long as you are using recent az CLI based on MS Graph API

```
az ad sp update --id ${azuread_application.this.application_id} --set preferredSingleSignOnMode='saml'
```

should get you going.

broader example in terraform with https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azuread/issues/173